# how to use markdown and eco together?

Tags: docpad

I want to have a template variable pre-processed in a markdown doc.

I tried converting the filename to `file.html.md.eco` but it just comes out as plain text - ie the markdown plugin doesn't seem to get applied.
The file just as `html.md` renders fine.

Is it needed to add the plugins to the `docpad.coffee` to make sure they're applied when using multiple passes?

the FAQ states how to use multiple processors

http://docpad.org/docs/faq

> ... Alternatively, we can get pretty inventive and do something like this: .html.md.eco which means process this with Eco, then Markdown and finally render it as HTML.

Comment: Could be an issue with indentation. Can you upload a copy of the file in question to something like Dropbox or gist.github.com

Comment: when i went to the files i had it seems to work now. i dont think it was indentation as the whole file just didn't render at all... but i'll keep an eye out, thanks!